# Where does the list of iPhone movies in Finder come from?

Tags: iphone, itunes, finder

When I connect my iPhone to my MacBook, then go to Finder and click in the left column my iPhone name, I get to the syncing tool. At the top of this are the tabs "General", "Music", "Movies", etc. Under the tab "Movies", there's a list of movies that I can check, presumably to add to the iPhone.

How is that list populated and how do I edit it? Some of those movies listed do not exist anywhere on my MacBook anymore. On the other hand, there are movies I'd like to add to my phone which are to listed but are on my MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

The answer turns out to be that those are the old "home videos" that were uploaded to iTunes. They can now be found in the "Home Videos" tab in the Apple TV app.

To get there, open the app and click *Edit* in the sidebar.
[image: AppleTV app with edit button highlighted]

Then tick the tickbox for *Home Videos*.
[image: AppleTV app with Home Videos ticked]